# ASP.net web api returns list of empty objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have an action, which shoeuld return a limited list of store items from a DB, here the code below

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ProductInfo> GetTop(int amount = 5)
    {
        var mostPopulardProductIds = dbe.SalesOrderDetail.GroupBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Count())
            .Take(amount)
            .Select(p => p.Key)
            .ToList();

        var result = dbe.Product
            .Where(p => mostPopulardProductIds.Contains(p.ProductID))
            .Select(p => new ProductInfo()
            {
                Id = p.ProductID,
                Name = p.Name
            }
            ).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

and here's my ProductInfo class

```
[DataContract]
public class ProductInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public
}
```

But when I try to access it via browser, I get list of empty objects, which are looking like the 1st pic

But debugger shows me, that result variable containing normal objects with data

[image: smlresult]

[image: debugger result]

I've tried to return result through `Request.CreateResponse` method, but this still does not work

Comment: Can you add datamember attribute to ProductInfo class variables?

Comment: @Naruto, yep, thanks, now it works, now my question looks like the stupid one :D. But thanks a lot, man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please add DataMember attribute to class properties, change ProductInfo class

```
[DataContract]
public class ProductInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

More about [Data Member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)